# Button Content Margin

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I can't work out how to get rid of the margin around a button's content. Here is some example XAML:

```
<Button Background="Red" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid Background="Blue" Margin="0">
        <TextBlock Text="me" Padding="0"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

I can't seem to get rid of the red bit. Has anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the control template for the button. You can have alook at the following links
http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2007/07/creating-custom-wpf-button-template-in.html
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163497.aspx